# insertion sort in assembly does not work

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86, nasm, insertion-sort

I have tried to write an insertion sort in assembly (nasm), and it doesn't work (always sent segmentation fault).
I tried to search the source of the problem for really long time and I cannot find it,
can someone please help me to find the problem?
thank you.

```
sort:

pushad
mov ebp,esp;creating stack frame
mov ebx,[ebp+36]; ebx saves pointer to the array
mov ecx,[ebp+40];ecx saves the srray size
mov esi,4 ; i


for_l1:
    ;edx=temp,esi=i,edi=j
    mov edx,[ebx+esi]
    mov edi,esi;j=i
    sub edi,4;j=i-1
    while_l1:


        cmp edx,[ebx+edi]; if(temp<array[j])
        jge end_while1
        ;array[j+1]=array[j], j-=1
        mov eax,[ebx+edi]
        mov [ebx+edi+4],eax
        sub edi,4
        cmp edi,0
        jge while_l1;if(j>=0)
    end_while1:
        ;array[j+1]=temp
        mov[ebx+edi+4],edx
        add esi,4;i+=1
        dec ecx; decreasing the size of the array needed to sort
        cmp ecx,1;if(size==1)
        jg for_l1
    finished1:
        popad
        ret 8
```

Comment: How are you invoking this? Why do you use `ebp+36`? Looks very large offset. Have you verified in a debugger that you get the arguments correctly? Have you single stepped your code to see where it goes wrong? *Edit: oh, I see the large offset is due to the `pushad`.

Comment: yes, the large offset is indeed due the pushad,do you notice anything that can cause the segmentation fault?

Comment: Use a debugger. As a bare minumum, tell which instruction faults. And show how you invoke this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure *array size* represents the number of elements and that it doesn't contain the total length of the array?

Then perhaps you could code

```
mov ecx,[ebp+40];ecx saves the srray size
shr ecx,2
```